# Request payload is transformed to query params after POST request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a React application where I am sending form data to the server using `axios`.

I am able to send the data and the database is also updated. The problem is, after sending the request, the data in the form is getting attached to the `url` as though I was passing query params.

Here is the component with the form

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from '../../axios'

function HomePage(props) {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('')

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        switch(event.target.name) {
            case "name":
                setName(event.target.value)
                break
            case "email":
                setEmail(event.target.value)
                break
            case "password":
                setPassword(event.target.value)
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }

    const validation = () => {
        let isValid = true
        return isValid
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if(validation()) {
            let data = {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }

            axios.post('/user/create-user', data)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    required
                    name="name" 
                    value={name} 
                    onChange={handleChange}/>
                <input 
                    type="email" 
                    required
                    name="email" 
                    value={email} 
                    onChange={handleChange}/>
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    required
                    name="password" 
                    value={password} 
                    onChange={handleChange}/>
                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

After clicking on submit button, I see the `url` with form data in the browser.

[image]

I can also see the status (canceled) in `dev tools`.

I think the browser is navigating to the new `url` with query params, I don't know why.It's not just in `Chrome`.

[image]

The console is showing "Navigated to" in blue with the unwanted route with query params.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form element defaults to `GET` as action, and also you've not used `preventDefault` on the submit, so by default the form will make get request.

add form attribute `method="post"` on the form tag,
and also add `e.preventDefault()` to `handleSubmit`.

some references
[Forms in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html),
[Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I think you mean, `method="post"`, thanks it worked.